# How does browser functionality affect cordova/phonegap app?

Tags: android, html, datetime, cordova

This [page](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html) tells me what HTML5 types work in various phones and which don't.

The `input type="datetime"` doesn't appear to work in android for example.

However that page is for the android mobile browser. I'm unclear if it would work in a cordova app that builds for android? Is the cordova app taking the datetime input type that works on my desktop, wrapping it into a native implementation and building in android? Or, say datetime does not work on my desktop browser, will that affect whether datetime works in a cordova build android app? Or is it using android's understanding of datetime and therefore would not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the cordova app taking the datetime input type that works on my desktop, wrapping it into a native implementation and building in android?

No.

> Or, say datetime does not work on my desktop browser, will that affect whether datetime works in a cordova build android app?

No.

> Or is it using android's understanding of datetime and therefore would not work?

That depends upon your definition of "android".

As with Windows, OS X, and Linux, there are many browsers available for Android. Major "name brand" ones, like Chrome and Firefox, use their own Web rendering engines. Many of the smaller ones rely on Android's `WebView` widget, which is also what Cordova uses for rendering your Web content. It is whether `WebView` handles `datetime` or not that matters. Since `WebView` itself varies by Android OS version, you will need to test your Cordova app on representative Android versions -- using devices or emulators -- to determine whether all of your Web content works.

With respect to the Web page that you linked to, its definition of "Android" is limited and (IMHO) generally obsolete. If you can find one, you will be better served with a resource that is more explicit about different Android versions and browsers.

Comment: thanks for your response!! I understand what's going on much better now.